# Tkinter : Use Button Click command get text box value and save in html

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, jinja2

I created a small program to get user entered text and save the text in a html file. Here is my example small program.

```
from tkinter import *
from jinja2 import Template

root=Tk()
textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonSave=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Save",
                command=lambda: createCaseDetails())
buttonSave.pack()

def createCaseDetails():
    # Create The template html for case report
    t = Template("""
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" >
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <title>Case Report</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1><span class="blue">&lt;</span>Evidence<span class="blue">&gt;</span> <span class="yellow">System Information</pan></h1>
                    <h2>Created with love by bluebear119 </h2>
                    <h3>Case Description</h3>
                        <p>{{Case_Description}</p>
                </body>
            </html>
            """)

    f = open('Case Report.html', 'w')
    inputvalue = textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(inputvalue)
    message = t.render(Case_Description=inputvalue)

f.write(message)
f.close()
print("Case Report.html file saved.")

mainloop()
```

But when I implement this in my huge code, I cannot use the variable since is from same class but in another function's variable.
I defined the createCaseDetails() function at top-level,but my text box is in another function, button is in another function as well. How can I press the button and save the Case description text in html.

The textbox and button will define in a same class like this:

```
Class CreateCaseInterface(Frame):

    def caseInformation(self):
        ...
        Case_Description_text=Text(self.caseInfoFrame,width=30,height=11,yscrollcommand=CaseDescripyscrollbar.set)
        Case_Description_text.grid(row =4, column =1,pady=5)

    def UACaseManagement(self):
        Executebtn = Button(self.UACaseManagementFrame, text="Execute for create and save the case file", command=createCaseDetails(self),width=30,height=5)
        Executebtn.grid(row=12,column= 4,sticky=W,pady=5,columnspan=2)


def createCaseDetails(self):
    ...
    # As I already know declare global is not the solution
    inputvalue = Case_Description_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(inputvalue)
    message = t.render(Case_Description_text=inputvalue)
```

The error will be cannot use the variable `Case_Description_text` in `createCaseDetails()` function.

Full Code for Huge file Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I8TPSPf8XmtaeJ3Vm9Pk0hM1rOgqIcaRMgVUNxyn8ok

Comment: Can you just assign it to self.Case_Description_text ?

Comment: Once I assign : AttributeError: 'CreateCaseInterface' object has no attribute 'Case_Description_text'
So any ideas for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned it as a class variable, you've assigned it as a variable in that function's scope, so when the function ends the variable is destroyed. You need to assign it to an attribute of the class using `self`, ie.

```
def caseInformation(self):
    self.Case_Description_text = ...

def createCaseDetails(self):
    # can then reference it here
    inputvalue = self.Case_Description_text.get()
```

Generally it's good practice to assign tkinter widgets to class variables, so that all of your widgets are accessible from other places.

Comment: Can you modify my code, I get this error 
Executebtn = Button(self.UACaseManagementFrame, text="Execute for create and save the case file", command=self.createCaseDetails(self),width=30,height=5)
TypeError: createCaseDetails() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: You don't need to pass self to a class method, it's passed automatically, so that should say '...command=self.createCaseDetails, width=30...'

Comment: You are right, I should assign  self.Case_Description_text = ... first XD